# How to delete all SMS from SIM800l?

Tags: arduino, sms, iot, at-command, sim800l

I used to have an **SIM800l** module that I do not know exactly how I set up, but every time I deleted a SMS from the first memory location, the other SMS were moved up to the position of the first SMS, always occupying the position number one in storage.

**Does anyone know how to set up my new module like that?**

With such setup, in order to delete all SMS, I just repeatedly sent the command `AT+CMGD=1` so that I didn't need to change the indices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SMS messages changing position sound really strange, and I'm not sure it was what actually happened. Read all my answer to discover what I think could be the actual explanation.

**TL;DR**: you are lucky, because you can free your SMS memory with a single command: **`AT+CMGDA`**.

---

According to [AT command guide](https://usermanual.wiki/Document/SIM80020SeriesAT20Command20ManualV110.1196360122/view) its syntax is really simple:

```
AT+CMGDA=<type>
```

where `<type>` has a different meaning according to the `+CMGF` setting.

In **text mode** (after `AT+CMGF=1`):

- `"DEL READ"` - Delete all read messages
- `"DEL UNREAD"` - Delete all unread messages
- `"DEL SENT"` - Delete all sent SMS
- `"DEL UNSENT"` - Delete all unsent SMS
- `"DEL INBOX"` - Delete all received SMS
- `"DEL ALL"` - Delete all SMS

In **PDU mode** (after `AT+CMGF=0`, that's not actually required, as it is the default value):

- `1` - Delete all read messages
- `2` - Delete all unread messages
- `3` - Delete all sent SMS
- `4` - Delete all unsent SMS
- `5` - Delete all received SMS
- `6` - Delete all SMS

---

**What you need** is to provide

```
AT+CMGDA="DEL ALL"
```

if you are operating in text mode, or

```
AT+CMGDA=6
```

if you are operating in PDU mode.

**Even better**, you can get rid of just *read* messages by issuing

```
AT+CMGDA="DEL READ"
```

if you are operating in text mode, or

```
AT+CMGDA=1
```

if you are operating in PDU mode. I suspect the latter was the command you actually used to provide.

Comment: Yes. My mistake in this was to delete the first SMS quickly and the next SMS was always in the first memory.

Comment: @mohammad I'm glad you solved your issue.